# NameError: global name 'glGenVertexArrays' is not defined

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am using OpenGL version 3.0, when I try:

```
vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
```

I get:

> > NameError: global name 'glGenVertexArrays' is not defined

Somebody knows why?

Here is what I am importing:

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from OpenGLContext.arrays import *
self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
```

Also when I run:

```
dir(OpenGL.GL)
```

In the output I cannot find the function: glGenVertexArrays

Comment: Have you defined `glGenVertexArrays()` some where in your code? Please provide complete code!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you did this:

```
import pyopengl
```

then you'd want to do something like

```
vao = pyopengl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
```

to actually use the function.

However, it looks to me like `glGenVertexArrays` [takes *2* arguments](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGenVertexArrays.html) so you'll still need to resolve that I think ...